# How to use GROUP by in multiple items per Invoice number?

Tags: sql-server

A master table contains a series of invoices with multiple items.

Obviously, if an invoice has multiple items, the result will produce multiple records for the same invoice number. So the sum of the Amounts includes several repetition of the same invoice number.

Been racking my brains to fabricate an SQL Query to simultaneously create the sum just one single invoice number even it has different line items.

Any ideas ?
The current result looks like:

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIoQE.jpg)

But it should be just 1 line under that Invoice number.

The code I got is:

```
SELECT
  STUFF(dbo.Invoice.CustomerPO, 1, 2, '') AS [Customer PO],
  '' AS Blank,
  ISNULL(dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo, dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNo) AS [Invoice Number],
  dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice AS Net,
  dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes AS GST,
  dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice + dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes AS Gross,
  dbo.Invoice.EntryDate AS [Invoice Date],
  dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID,
  dbo.Customers.CustomerID,
  dbo.ItemSpecs.ItemSpecID
FROM
  dbo.SalesOrder WITH (NOLOCK)
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomerBillTo
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.GLAccounts AS GLAccounts_1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.GLAccounts AS GLAccounts_2
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Territories WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Customers.TerritoryID = dbo.Territories.TerritoryID
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Invoice WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Customers.CustomerID = dbo.Invoice.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UOMs WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.InvoiceDetails.PriceUOMID = dbo.UOMs.UOMID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesOrderDetails WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.InvoiceDetails.SalesOrderDetailID = dbo.SalesOrderDetails.SalesOrderDetailID ON dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID = dbo.InvoiceDetails.InvoiceID ON GLAccounts_2.GLAccountID = dbo.InvoiceDetails.CogsGLAccountID ON GLAccounts_1.GLAccountID = dbo.InvoiceDetails.InvGLAccountID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GLAccounts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CurrencyCodes ON dbo.GLAccounts.CurrencyCodeID = dbo.CurrencyCodes.CurrencyCodeID ON dbo.InvoiceDetails.SalesGLAccountID = dbo.GLAccounts.GLAccountID ON dbo.CustomerBillTo.CustomerBillToID = dbo.Invoice.CustomerBillToID ON dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = dbo.SalesOrderDetails.SalesOrderID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      dbo.ARPaymentDetails.InvoiceID,
      MAX(dbo.ARPayment.EntryDate) AS LastPaymentDate
    FROM
      dbo.ARPaymentDetails
      INNER JOIN dbo.ARPayment ON dbo.ARPaymentDetails.ARPaymentID = dbo.ARPayment.ARPaymentID
    WHERE
      (dbo.ARPayment.Posted = 1)
    GROUP BY
      dbo.ARPaymentDetails.InvoiceID
  ) AS ARPayments ON dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID = ARPayments.InvoiceID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.listToTable(
    'Partially Shipped,Partially Shipped and/or Partially Invoiced,Shipped,Shipped + Partially Invoiced,Invoiced,Cancelled',
    ','
  ) AS SalesOrderStatus ON dbo.SalesOrderDetails.SOStatus = SalesOrderStatus.Position
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemSpecs WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.InvoiceDetails.ItemSpecID = dbo.ItemSpecs.ItemSpecID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ShippingDetails WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.InvoiceDetails.ShippingDetailID = dbo.ShippingDetails.ShippingDetailID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesReps WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.SalesOrder.SalesRepID = dbo.SalesReps.SalesRepID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Shipping WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.ShippingDetails.ShippingID = dbo.Shipping.ShippingID
WHERE
  (dbo.Customers.CustomerNo = 'omx')
GROUP BY
  dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo,
  dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNo,
  STUFF(dbo.Invoice.CustomerPO, 1, 2, ''),
  dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice,
  dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes,
  dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice + dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes,
  dbo.Invoice.EntryDate,
  dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID,
  dbo.Customers.CustomerID,
  dbo.ItemSpecs.ItemSpecID
ORDER BY
  [Invoice Number] DESC
```

Comment: Ignoring any issues with correcting where exactly in that query you're getting multiple lines, could you not just use `DISTINCT`? EDIT: never mind, I see the lines you're trying to merge together are all different. What issues are you having with just using `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`?

Comment: @Trish you are using to much unnecessary code ,sum and group by methods can give the desired result. correct your query.

Comment: Start over. First and foremost, mixing the use of right and left joins is just bad! It is difficult to read, difficult to understand, difficult to debug. Next, remove all the tables that are not needed - and there are many of them. ShippingDetails - why do you join to this table if you never use any column from it? Repeat that for most of the other tables. You did not join to InvoiceDetails correctly. Get the basic query correct **FIRST** before you attempt to add a total (at Invoice level?).

Comment: And one last thing. You said "should be one line under that invoice number". It is not clear what your goal is. It could be that you want one row per invoice number with the sum of all associated invoice detail rows for the amount columns. But that generally precludes the inclusion of any particular detail value - like itemspecid. OTOH, perhaps you want an additional row for each invoice that contains the summed detail amounts. It would help to see a complete and correct example of your data and your goal,

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ZLK, if you take out anything in the group by that refers to InvoiceDetail, and add a sum() around each of the InvoiceDetail columns in the select list, then you will get what you want.

So the select list looks like:

```
SELECT  STUFF(dbo.Invoice.CustomerPO, 1, 2, '') AS [Customer PO], '' AS Blank, ISNULL(dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo, dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNo) AS [Invoice Number], 
    sum(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice AS Net, 
    sum(dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes) AS GST, 
    sum(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice + dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes) AS Gross,
    dbo.Invoice.EntryDate AS [Invoice Date], dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID, dbo.Customers.CustomerID,
```

and the group by:

```
GROUP BY ISNULL(dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo, dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNo), STUFF(dbo.Invoice.CustomerPO, 1, 2, ''), 
dbo.Invoice.EntryDate, dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID, dbo.Customers.CustomerID
```